# PDO login script failing

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Thanks to my last question im updating my site to PDO, i figured id start on my front pages and work my way deeper, and ive hit my first hurdle and fallen over, my login script.

login-exec.php EDITED

```
session_start();

include_once ('connect.php');   

$Email = isset($_POST['Email']) ? $_POST['Email'] : "Email Never Sent";
$Password = isset($_POST['Password']) ? $_POST['Password'] : "Password Never Sent";

$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM members WHERE Email = :Email AND Password = :Password");
$stmt->bindParam(":Email"   , $Email    );
$stmt->bindParam(":Password", $Password);
$stmt->execute();
$member = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
if ($member)    
    { 
            $_SESSION['SESS_MEMBER_ID'] = $member['Member_ID'];
            $_SESSION['SESS_POST_AS'] = $member['Post_As'];
            $_SESSION['SESS_AUTH'] = $member['auth'];
            session_write_close();
            header('location: index.php');
            exit(); 
    } else  {
        header("location: ?p=login-failed");
        exit();
    }
```

connect.php

```
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test;charset=utf8', 'root', '');
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
```

EDIT: Now i get sent to the login-failed page, so does my problem now lie in what this page received from the form?

I know my $password is plain text, i was using md5 before and once i get this working ill implement some better protection

Comment: You should turn up the level of PHP error reporting probably. If what you posted in login-exec.php is correct, you have one closing brace too many, which should be producing an error.

Comment: `$count > 1` seems bad as there's only going to be one result.

Comment: Give us an error message, using try...catch procedure when creating PDO object: http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.construct.php

Comment: @TomvanderWoerdt Seems `$count == 1` would indicate a successful login, so that should probably be `$count >= 1` in the very least.

Comment: first use try catch to check what happening there..

Comment: [PDO query fails but I can't see any errors. How to get an error message from PDO?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15990858/285587)

Comment: post your error also, if coming

Comment: ive thrown in a try..catch and removed the extra }, now im getting the login-failed page

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This will work, for you to check if a result was found or not:

```
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
if($result)
{
    //...
}
else
{
    //...
}
```

Also note that you always have to put

```
session_start();
```

at the top of the page, otherwise it won't work.

$member doesn't really make sense here, where do you init it? $member should act as a row but in this case, $result would do the job for you.

I recommend taking a look at [phpass](http://www.openwall.com/phpass/) for password protection.

You should also make logic around the POST, you can never be sure that anything is really posted unless you check. The [Ternary Operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_operation) can be handy here:

```
$Password = isset($_POST['Password']) ? $_POST['Password'] : "Password Never Sent";
```

You should not use try catch around the whole page if it's only to catch a failed pdo connection, that should be a part of your connect file.

I'd avoid using "?p=login-failed", since it's easy to manipulate if you don't have any valid validations ongoing.

I personally don't like the bindParam approach, it makes more sense to me to execute an array of parameters onto the statement:

```
$stmt->execute(array(":Email"=>$Email, ":Password"=>$Password));
```

But your approach shouldn't be causing an error in this case.

Note that you don't need exit(); after header();

I hope that my comments help.

Comment: trying this i get the login-failed page, ive updated my main post

Comment: Alright. I'll see if I can figure something out, it'd be nice if you could up-vote, otherwise I'll be forced to delete my answer because of the previous down-vote. Also: Have you checked the actual values of $Email and $Password? You should use an if else statement to check if the values are posted (with the approach that I showed you and you're using, you just have to check the actual values).

Comment: i dont have enough rep to upvote but ive accepted your answer as its works now with your answer after i edited my forms

Answer (score 0):

Put your connection attempt into a try/catch and then you will see the error

```
try {
    $dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test;charset=utf8', 'root', '');
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
}
```

Comment: @Gordon Well no he doesn't actually. He is just saying `correctly` in my opinion that they should be used in conjunction with the normal `php error reporting`. In other words you should have `error-reporting` turned on during development, A condition that it is quite obvious many developers dont do.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the problem is `if ($count > 1)` and should be

```
if ($count > 0)
```

or

```
if ($count == 1)
```

if sql returns 1 row which I assume is what you want.

Comment: or `if ($count > 0)` or `if ($count != 0)`

Comment: I agree, depends on database entries :D

Answer (score 0):

in addition to setting up a proper error reporting, also change

```
$count = $stmt->rowCount();

if ($count > 1)
```

to

```
$member = $stmt->fetch();

if ($member)
```

to make the code consistent

Comment: trying this i get the login-failed page, ive updated my main post

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
if ($count > 0)
```

**or**

```
if ($count >= 1) 
{
    session_start();    
    $_SESSION['SESS_MEMBER_ID'] = $member['Member_ID'];
    $_SESSION['SESS_POST_AS'] = $member['Post_As'];
    $_SESSION['SESS_AUTH'] = $member['auth'];
    session_write_close();
    header('location: index.php');
    exit(); 
}
```